# read_excel cannot able to read xls(MS excel 5.0/95 Workbook) while can be read with saving as .xlsx

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

I am really learner in this R, Python area and faced some problem that read_xls cannot read .xls(MS excel 5.0/95 Workbook) but only my R studio shows a 0x0 tibble.

I tried to make a reprex but it showed me as below so did not understand 'path' does not exist while I can see the result in my trial so I copied both cases.

So this problematic file can be read only if I saved it as .xlsx. I can do with this way as a workaround but I want to use original file so that my code can be automatic and work within my code without effort outside like saving as .xlsx.

This problematic xls file can be found from the link while it is .zip file so should be extracted for trial and can be check file type as MS excel 5.0/95 Workbook only if you go to the save menu.

--reprex trial--

```
library(readxl)
read_excel("tdocList_3GU_2017-05-19_18h25.xls")
#> Error: path does not exist: 'tdocList_3GU_2017-05-19_18h25.xls'
read_excel("tdocList_3GU_2017-05-19_18h25_xlsx.xlsx")
#> Error: path does not exist: 'tdocList_3GU_2017-05-19_18h25_xlsx.xlsx'
```

--my trial--

```
library(readxl)
read_excel("tdocList_3GU_2017-05-19_18h25.xls")

A tibble: 0 x 0
read_excel("tdocList_3GU_2017-05-19_18h25_xlsx.xlsx")

A tibble: 2,159 x 32
tdocList_3GU_2017-05-19_18h25_xlsx.xlsx
```

Tdoc Title Source Contact Contact ID Type Type supplemen~ For Abstract Secretary Rema~ `Agenda item so~

1 R2-1~ Agen~ Chair~ Richar~ 14160 agen~ NA Appr~ NA NA NA
2 R2-1~ RAN2~ ETSI Juha K~ 21609 repo~ NA Appr~ NA NA NA
3 R2-1~ LS o~ CT1 Jaehyu~ 44912 LS in NA Acti~ NA NA NA
4 R2-1~ LS o~ CT1 Lena C~ 38080 LS in NA Info~ NA NA NA
5 R2-1~ Repl~ CT1 Mikael~ 40034 LS in NA Info~ NA NA NA
6 R2-1~ Repl~ CT1 Chen-h~ 57105 LS in NA Info~ NA NA NA
7 R2-1~ Repl~ CT1 Jennif~ 43418 LS in NA Acti~ NA NA NA
8 R2-1~ LS o~ CT1 Chen-h~ 57105 LS in NA Acti~ Offline~ NA NA
9 R2-1~ Resp~ RAN1 Albert~ 63913 LS in NA Acti~ NA NA NA
10 R2-1~ LS o~ RAN1 Alexey~ 46112 LS in NA Acti~ NA NA NA

... with 2,149 more rows, and 21 more variables: Agenda item , Agenda item description , `TDoc sort order within agenda item<dbl>,TDoc Status<chr>,Reservation date<dttm>, Uploaded <dttm>,Is revision of<chr>,Revised to<chr>, Rel <chr>, Specification <chr>, Version <chr>,Related WIs<chr>, CR <chr>,CR revision<chr>,CR category<chr>,TSG CR Pack<lgl>,Reply to<chr>, LS_To <chr>, LS_Cc <chr>,Original LS<chr>,Reply in`

[file download link as I cannot find where I can upload my test file](https://www.3gpp.org/ftp/tsg_ran/WG2_RL2/TSGR2_98/Tdoclists/tdocList_3GU_2017-05-19_18h25.zip)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no solution to this in R, other than converting to a more recent excel format. Neither `readxl` or `xlsx` handle excel formats as old as this.